# Smallest Eigen value of Matrix + other matrix less than greatest value eigen value of Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-optimization

I've been working on this problem for a little bit and I'm not sure if it can be proven with the given information. Any help would be greatly appreciated to either confirm or deny my suspicion.

Assume that Q is a symmetric n × n matrix, c ∈ $R^n$ is a nonzero (column) vector, and μ is a positive number.
Consider the symmetric matrix R = Q + μcc$^T$ .

Using λ1 = smallest eigenvalue of R = min (${v\neq0}$) {$$\frac{v^TRv}{v^tv}$$}

Show that for *n>1* 
***$$λ1(R) ≤ λn(Q).$$***
Where λn(Q) is the largest eigenvalue of Q

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Take a vector $v \ne 0$ with $c^T v = 0$.  Then $R v = Q v$.  Thus

$$\lambda_1(R) \le \dfrac{v^T R v}{v^T v} = \dfrac{v^T Q v}{v^T v} \le \lambda_n(Q) $$

Comment: Many Thanks Mr. Isreal!

Comment: Wait sorry, if we pick v such that c$^t$v = 0, will it satisfy the initial min problem (related to the smallest eigen value of R)? Thank!

Comment: The minimum  $\le$ any particular one.